# Display Error: The display template had an error

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

```
Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it by fixing the template or by changing the display template used in either the Web Part properties or Result Types.


Template '~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Control_SearchResults.js' not found or has syntax errors. (LoadTemplate: )
```

I am getting this error when searching from a different machine. It works fine when I search within the server. The .js file is not missing and I don't think there are syntax errors in them as I haven't touched their contents.

Similar questions had solutions like adding the site to the trusted sites list which didn't work for me.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the file is actually published, so that there is a major version for users to find that do not have edit permissions on it

Comment: Yes, the file is published. I've also compared its configuration with my other machine which is not having the issue and they are the same.

Comment: use an admin account, does it still do the same? also is both JS files to compare the same or different?

Comment: Same thing happens with an admin account. The .js files are the same; they're default SharePoint Search templates.

Comment: Is there an error in the Browser Dev tools?

Comment: The search suddenly stopped working on all site collections in my SPO, I have checked all templates and js files to be published, tried adding new search result web parts and after two days of searching for a fix, what has helped was simply re-indexing the root site collection.

Answer (score 1):

You must publish not only the display template file but also any refinement items that you may be using on the search page.

Go through everything in the SharePoint Design Manager: Edit Display Templates page and make sure that the Approval Status is "Approved" for everything on the page in question.

You get there by going to `Site Settings` -> `Site Collection Administration` -> `Go to top level site settings`.

From Top Level site:  `Site Collection Admin` -> `Search Result Types`.

There is a link within the first sentence at the top of the page for `crafting a display template in HTML`. Click on the `display template` link to get to the approval page.

Answer (score 0):

On SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as Administrator run the following command:

> Enable-SPFeature SearchWebParts -url central_admin_url

This resolved the above issue in my environment. Make sure the URL is the administration URL (E.g. : http://sp-server:11186 ), not the intranet/default site URL.

Comment: Not sure why it is down vote. I think your solution is best among all.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in o365 and had to go to this specific page and publish a major version on the html display templates:

{YourSharePointSite}/_layouts/15/DesignDisplayTemplates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

FOR SOME WEIRD REASON I FIXED MINE BY DOING IISRESET
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Open other Site Collection using SharePoint Designer and go to top path and copy the `Control_SearchResults.js`  to same path at your Site Collection that has the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you extend the explanation, please?

Comment: If i am not wrong, M.Ashkboos meant you need to copy "Control_SearchResults.js" from any site collection (if available) where its working properly, to you site collection where you are getting error. (In a way resetting Control_SearchResults.js to its default state)

Comment: YES,I mean that

Answer (score -1):

None of the above worked for me. What worked was granting full control access to the template's .js and .html files to all my users.

Comment: Full control to all users? That is a huge security risk and certainly not needed